# Can I create a parameter from a service in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I need to set a parameter (an integer) in the service container using a service in much the same way that I can create a service using another service as defined in the service config by defining the factory class and method.

The only way I can think of to do this is to wrap the value in a class and create that class as a service using the method above which seems a bit awkward to me.

Any ideas?

EDIT

To clarify. There is an integer value that I need to inject into a number of different services. This value is calculated by a service.

If it were an object then I could define it as a service, and create it using the factory class and definition parameters and then inject this service into the other services where it is required.

Is it possible to do this for an integer value or will I have to wrap it in a Value Object / Class in order to do this?

Comment: You cannot create or set a parameter in a service since parameters (and other config values) are read before the service container and the services it holds are built.

Comment: You can (of course) give parameters at each method call... The service-class is a kind of static since you use that class all the execution time over and over again.

Comment: Consider updating your question with a specific use case.  From what I can tell your proposed approach is the way to go but I'm not completely sure what your as asking.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than injecting the result of a service calculation is injecting the service itself:

```
class ProviderService {
    public function calculateResult() {
        return 42; // your integer result
    }
}

class ConsumerService {
    private $provider;
    public function __construct(ProviderService $provider) {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }
    public function execute() {
        $result = $this->provider->calulateResult();
        // business logic
    }
}
```

If the calulation of your integer value is expensive, you can cache it in the `ProviderService`.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it may sound, a value cannot be a service. So you cannot inject a value derived from a service. If you keep your configuration as-is, you need to define a value object or you need to inject the "factory" service to the service which need to calculate the value.

If the value ONLY depends from the configuration, you can add a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html#create-a-compilerpass) which calculate the value once and set it to all services which need it. During a compiler pass, you can alter the arguments for a Service constructor or add a call to a setter method.

If the value need to be determined at runtime, then it make sense to create a new service. That's because there should be a service which "detect" the change and "notify" all the dependant service.